# $.getJSON is not working in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

The below is my code java script which working in Firefox very well but not in chrome or other.

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/myapp/getUploadStatus.htm?jsoncallback=?', function(data) {alert(data)});
```

And in server side i'm returning proper JSON data with the json function name like.

```
jQuery15205480379721357835_1345286865781({"percentage":0,"cpercentage":0,"cfile":"23.gif","uploadFiles":"noData"})
```

This working fine in FF but not in any other, In chrome it's not hitting to my server also.
Means the request is not going to server.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Krushna,
How are you running your code ? Can you also put your url address too ?

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong but whether it is correct url `.htm?jsoncallback=?'`

Comment: @caligula Yes I have visited lot of site , and got some idea, It always working with FF but not in chrome or other.

Comment: @ Pushkar i;m hitting to my local host

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js

Comment: Do you see some errors in the Chrome developer console? And in the `Network` tab? Can you see the request fire?

Comment: @thakrage , there is no error in console and request also not going as it's not showing on network tab.

Comment: I got the problem , the problem is ”XMLHttpRequest doesn’t work while submitting a form (useful for progress tracking)” in Chrome/Safari due to Webkit Bug 23933

Answer (score 1):

I'm always using the following jQuery for JSON
**javascript**:

```
var thedata = "hey";    
$.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     url: 'your url',
     data: 'mydata='+thedata,
     cache: false,
     success: function(data) {
       alert(data.callback);
     }
    });
```

And an **PHP** example:

```
if(isset($_POST['mydata'])) {
 $callback = "This is what I've got: ".$_POST['mydata'];
 echo json_encode(array('callback'=>$callback));
}
```

In this simple example you'll get an JS alert: This is what I've got: hey

Comment: +1. I once tried to get JSON using `getJSON` and it didn't work at all, but when I replaced it with `$.ajax`, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
event.preventDefault();
```